# Generate 10 queries to run in SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a driver table, date_driver_table that contains 10 dates. Jan 2014, Feb 2014, ... Nov2014.

I need to run a query

```
select * from records_Jan2014 where recdate='Jan 2014'
```

This is query 1 . After this runs and puts the result set in a SQL server table, query 2,

```
select * from records_Feb2014 where recdate='Feb 2014'
```

will then run and do the same insert into SQL server table , and then query 3, and so forth until no dates left in driver table.

So in ssis I have an execute SQL task with full result set enabled that puts all the dates from date driver table in a variable called date with type object and then feeds into a for each loop with a variable called single date type string. A dat flow with source and a destination of a SQL server table. The problem is how do I set up a source to do query 1 then put the results in the table then do query 2 etc.

I was thinking maybe creating 10 files with SQL and then using the ole db source with file as the SQL that needs to run but sure there is a way to do this with the for each loop. Can anyone point me how to this ? The question is how to set up the for each loop so it runs query 1, puts into the table then runs query 2 and puts it into the table and so on until all the records are done.

Comment: You can set the source up as a *SQL Command from Variable*, have the `foreach` look build the SQL variable, which will look something like `select * from records_Jan2014 where recdate=@singleDate` in the expression builder.   I have no access to BIDS here, so I can't go into much detail.

Comment: How does "Jan 2014, Feb 2014, ... Jan 2015" compute to "10 dates" anyway?  Regardless, it would be best for you to construct one T-SQL script with all the queries you need to run, without using any looping anywhere.  If you need dynamic table names for use in future years or whatever, then make dynamic SQL within your one script.  I'm not seeing anything in your scenario that would require any features SSIS offers over straight T-SQL, unless you are doing it as a learning exercise.

Comment: Table name and record date both need to be changed for each query. Is there a limit to expression builder in terms of size of query ? One big script not suitable due to volumes of data for each month. You are right about it being more than 10 months. Lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used sql command expression pointing to a variable on the ADO.net Source . Then the variable was fed from an execute sql task which gave the list to process.